# Schema & Data Comparison from visual studio 2010

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible if we can compare schema and data from 2 different server considering the fact that it maybe 2 different window server as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in [certain versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193261(v=vs.100).aspx) of Visual Studio 2010 you can compare the schema and data of databases from two servers.